# send and receive message - mqlight synchronous mode

Tags: messaging, amqp, mq

Is there a way to send and receive messages using MQLight "AMQP" protocol in synchronous mode rather than non blocking asynchronous mode. If yes, please provide an example

All Examples posted here "https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/" show how to send asynchronous.

Thank you

Comment: Looking for example in Java client for MQLight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to force the MQ Light Java client to send and receive messages synchronously.

However you could use another Java client, for example the [Apache Qpid Proton](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) client for Java or the [Qpid JMS client](http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/). Both can do synchronous sending and receiving and both work with MQ Light.